# the difference meaning between humiliate and ridicule

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

i get new word, ridicule, that means making fun of someone in harsh way
how about humiliate. i think there both have similiarity but there both not a synonym. what is the difference ?

thanks

Comment: What does your research show? What do the dictionaries show? Please visit the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how to post a good question. You can edit your question to include more information.

Comment: Humiliation is the feeling a person has, very ashamed. And humiliating someone can lead to that person being humiliated/ashamed. Ridicule is making fun of someone in a mean way. That can lead to a person being humiliated but that is not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest difference is that when you ridicule someone, that person may be able to strike back: Demonstrate that your accusations are wrong, malicious, etc. When a person is humiliated, that's it. That person is humiliated. (Similar to "attacked" vs. "injured". A person who is attacked may be able to beat up their attacker. A person who is injured is injured. )